# :active selector of <a> tag without href attribute

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap pagination like this:

```
<ul class="pagination">  
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" >1</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" >2</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" >3</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" >4</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" >5</a></li></ul>
```

I want to change the border color of active element, I use :active selector:

```
a:active {
border: solid 2px #f51d19;}
```

But the :active selector doesn't work.

How can I change active element using a tag without href attribute?

Comment: may be try 
a:active {
border: solid 2px #f51d19 !important;}
 some times it need to be overright the existing css

Comment: its possible if you use javascript you could just add class active on the clicked <a> tag

Comment: @RaniMorelesRubillos If I add class active on that element, do I need remove this class when clicking other elements?

Comment: @JoyceLee try to look at what I have done hhttps://jsfiddle.net/qLgxrob1/2/

Comment: using active selector, a link becomes active when you click on it. your code works fine for it. but i think you want to make current page value in pagination active/different then others. this is not work of active selector. use a class to do your job.

Comment: @JoyceLee: what is an active element for you? During the click or after the click?

Comment: I wouldn't be using an `a` tag for something this isn't really a link (or anchor). What is clicking on the `a` tag meant to do besides giving a border to the clicked element?

Comment: Also note `:active` is for when the element is being activated, i.e clicked :https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:active

Answer (score 3):

Use an `<a>`nchor this way:

```
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
```

Add  `/`there

By simply adding a `/` at the end of a `href` value of `#` you will have the normal behavior invoked by the pseudo-classes without the jumping.

#### SNIPPET

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.top {
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
hr:first-of-type {
  margin: 10px auto;
}
hr {
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:link {
  color: blue;
}
a:visited {
  color: green;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
}
a:hover:after {
  color: black;
  content: ' and is HOVERed over';
}
a:active {
  color: magenta;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active:after {
  color: black;
  content: ' and is ACTIVE until you release your mouse button'
}
```

```html
<div class='top'>
  <h1>TOP</h1>
  <hr>
  <h2>Scroll to the bottom</h2>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
</div>
<a href='#'>LINK will jump</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href='#/'>LINK will NOT jump</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `:active` style is not applied, make sure (e.g. with the help of your browsers developer tools) that your style is not overwritten. In this case, use a higher specificity to make your styles apply.

Also: `href` is mandatory for an `a` tag. Just use a placeholder `href` lik this:

```
<a href="#" class="page-link">1</a>
```

As written in the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination):

> ```
> <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
>   <ul class="pagination">
>     <li>
>       <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
>         <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
>       </a>
>     </li>
>     <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
>     <li>
>       <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
>         <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
>       </a>
>     </li>
>   </ul>
> </nav>
> ```

Comment: the questioner is trying to changing  active element using a tag without href attribute

Comment: But if I use attribute href, it will be redirected to top of the page when I click on this element....

Comment: As the above is the origional quote from Bootstraps documention, this should not be the normal behavior... Are you sure you have all necessary Bootstrap .css and .js files properly included?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap adds active class to the li element. 
So you need to write following css to get border on active element.

```
li.active {border: solid 2px #f51d19;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use javascript here is what I have done.

```js
$('li a').on('click',function(){
  $('li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
a.active {
border: 2px solid  #f51d19 !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pagination">  
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" >1</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" >2</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" >3</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" >4</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" >5</a></li></ul>
```