# How to style a data-target anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, styling

So the issue is I use data-target in the **anchor(a)** tag instead of href, so I am not able to style it when its **active** . So I usually use **'a:active{styling}'** , but its not working for this one.

**Here is the JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sp1vh94u/4/**

Here is the code:

```
<ul >
        <li>
            <a data-target="#a" aria-controls="a" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">A</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-target="#b" aria-controls="b" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">B</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-target="#c" aria-controls="c" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">C</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Everything is working just fine, I need help with the styling thats all. :)

Comment: I don’t understand why you can’t style it on hover, could you show what you have tried?

Comment: @AHaworth Hi yes I am able to style it on hover, the thing is when its active, I am not able to style it. like when its clicked. This is supposed to be a naviagtion bar that opens a div according to the heading. Here is the JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sp1vh94u/4/

Comment: the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395461/active-selector-of-a-tag-without-href-attribute says to use `<a href='#/'>` but I didn't verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want avoid href then it is possible with JS.

```js
const as = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-tabs a')
as.forEach(a => a.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.classList.add('visited');
}))


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```css
.nav-tabs a{  
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.nav-tabs a:hover{
  color: orange;
}
.nav-tabs a:active{
  color: red;
}
.visited {
  color: white !important;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="navcontent" role="tabpanel">
<ul id="BarTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a href="#" data-target="#Mat" aria-controls="Mat" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Mat</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#" data-target="#Bat" aria-controls="Bat" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Bat</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#" data-target="#Cat" aria-controls="Cat" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Cat</a>
    </li>
</ul>       
  </div>
```